# What is the most efficient way to find the index of an element in a list, given only an element of a sublist (Python)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, indexing, nested-lists

I.e. Does something like the following exist?

```
lst = [["a", "b", "c"], [4,5,6],"test"]
print getIndex(lst, "a")
>>> 0
print getIndex(lst, 5)
>>> 1
print getIndex(lst, "test")
>>> 2
```

I know of the regular index() method but that only looks for the immediate elements.  I have a rough solution of making a new list, parsing through the superlist and adding "y" or "n" then looking for the index of the "y" in that one, but I feel there is much better way.  Thanks

Comment: No, there's no built-in to do that. It's not a hard function to write, e.g. using recursion. But is this homework?

Comment: It's not.  I just got a new job that requires lots of Python and I am trying to learn as I go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with [hellpanderrr's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4016674/hellpanderrr). It assumes that the main list elements will only be lists or strings. It fails if one searches on a list where another type is in the main list (the `in` operation raises a `TypeError`). E.g.:

```
lst2 = [["a", "b", "c"], [4, 5, 6], "test", 19]


>>> getIndex(lst2, 19)
# Ugly TypeError stack trace ensues
```

To fix this:

```
def getIndex2(lst, item):
    for n, i in enumerate(lst):
        try:
            if item == i or item in i:
                return n
        except TypeError:
            pass
    return None
```

Now:

```
>>> getIndex2(lst2, "test")
2
>>> getIndex2(lst2, 19)
3
```

There are several ways to accomplish the "equals or in" test. This solution bowls right through, using a "get forgiveness not permission" idiom to catch the times when the `in` on `i` is not type-appropriate.  It would also be possible to test the type of `i` before the `in` operation, or directly ask if `i` supports the in operation. But direct type inspection is often frowned upon, and strings and containers in Python have some complex overlapping capabilities. The "get forgiveness" approach gracefully handles those more simply.

Note that this also explicitly handles the case where no value is found.

```
>>> print getIndex2(lst2, 333)
None
```

While functions not returning a value implicitly return `None`, it is better to be explicit about such default cases.

By the by, this approach handles two levels. If the lists can be arbitrarily nested, a different approach, likely involving recursion, would be needed.

Comment: By the by, there are some degenerate cases for this algorithm, too, based on the odd overlap of string and container `in` operators. They're fairly easy to identify and rigorously test for, but would further complicate the code.

Answer (score 1):

use a generator

e.g. in >= Python 2.6, if you know the item exists in a sublist:

```
idx = next(i for i,v in enumerate(lst) if item in v)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the case shown by @Jonathan Eunice.

Comment: Actually, it passes the test in @JonathanEunices solution because the generator stops before it gets to `19`. However, if the original has random non-lists in it to be ignored, my solution can be modified to `idx = next(i for i,v in enumerate(lst2) if hasattr(v, '__contains__') and item in v)` or `idx = next(i for i,v in enumerate(lst2) if isinstance(v, list) and item in v)`

Comment: If you set the search target to `item = 19` it still throws a `TypeError`, no?

Comment: The original question doesn't specify that the outer list be expected to contain elements besides strings or lists. Requiring that every list entry have a `__contains__` method is enough to handle the case that a `lst` entry is an integer. The original question specifies "...given only an element of a sublist", which is enough to assume that all list entries are also lists (or strings, in the original example). Otherwise, the question should be modified.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getIndex(lst,item):
    for n,i in enumerate(lst):
        if (type(i) == list and item in i) or i == item
            return n
getIndex(lst,'test')
>>> 2
```

Comment: `getIndex([["a", "b", "c"], [4, 5, 6], "test", 19], 19)` raises a `TypeError`

Comment: We need some check there like `if (type(i) == list and item in i) or i == item`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the default function to the list: [list.index](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```
l = [[1,2,3], ['a', 'b', 'c']]

l[0].index(2)  # index 1
l[1].index('b') # index 1

This generates a "ValueError" if the item does not exist.
```